# VHDL create a vector of alternating zeros and ones

Tags: vhdl

I want to create an std_logic_vector of variable size, say size = y, of alternating 0's and 1's. 
A simple solution would be to use a loop or work with the clock cycle, but the program that I'm working on won't work with that. 
I'm looking basically of a solution that looks like the 'others' statement, i.e. (others => '0'). 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please mark one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a generate statement.

```
signal v : std_logic_vector (y-1 downto 0);
...
for i in v'range generate
   v(i) <= '1' when i mod 2 = 1 else '0';
end generate;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a VHDL function to create a vector?

```
function createVector(size : POSITIVE) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is
  variable temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(size - 1 downto 0);
begin
  for i in 0 to size - 1 loop
    if (i mod 2 = 0) then
      temp(i) := '0';
    else
      temp(i) := '1';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return temp;
end function;

-- usage
mysignal <= createVector(12);
```

It uses the modulo operator to check if the iterator variable is even or odd.

Comment: Or you could use it like `signal mysignal : std_logic_vector (11 downto 0) := createVector(12);`, which I think fits the question slightly better as an equivalent for `:= (others => '0')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum size of all SLVs you need to create, you can do something like this:

```
...
architecture rtl of my_entity is
  constant MAX_SIZE  : positive := 32; 
  constant PATTERN   : std_logic_vector(MAX_SIZE-1 downto 0) := X"AAAAAAAA"; -- 10101... in hex
  signal my_sig1     : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal my_sig2     : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
begin
...
  my_sig1 <= PATTERN(my_sig1'range);
  my_sig2 <= PATTERN(18 downto 1); -- phase shift
...
```

Not as elegant or flexible as other solutions, but it has the added benefit of letting you change the phase of the pattern by adjusting the slice range.

Answer (score 0):

Or make the starting value a parameter to the function.

```
  function alternating_ones_and_zeros(length : natural; starts_with : std_logic) return std_logic_vector is
    variable ret_val : std_logic_vector(length - 1 downto 0) := (others => starts_with);
  begin
    for i in length - 2 downto 0 loop
      ret_val(i) := not ret_val(i+1);
    end loop;

    return ret_val;
  end function alternating_ones_and_zeros;
```

Comment: And nicely avoids using a multiplying operator for those cases where a vector is generated during run time in a test bench.